# How to run rest of script after launching VLC?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vlc

After I launch VLC, the terminal seems locked up.  I can't even echo anything.  I've tried forking the launching of VLC but that seems to just crash the whole script as well.  **Are there any other options?**  I'm using cvlc by the way because I don't care about the user interface.  My other attempts are commented out with the hashtag:

```
echo "launching VLC player..."
# cvlc v412://dev/video1:standard=NTSC:width=640:height=480 &
# cvlc v412://dev/video1:standard=NTSC:width=640:height=480&
# cvlc & v412://dev/video1:standard=NTSC:width=640:height=480
cvlc v412://dev/video1:standard=NTSC:width=640:height=480

echo "can i see this in terminal?"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending `cvlc` to the background with `&` works for me.

```
echo "launching VLC player..."
cvlc v412://dev/video1:standard=NTSC:width=640:height=480 &
echo "can i see this in terminal?"
```

Comment: i forgot to re-try that.  something else was broken before reaching that line.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one: Append `vlc://quit` to the end of the command. Not sure why it works, but it does. For example:

```
cvlc rtsp://$IP/$CAM_STRING --sout file/avi:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).avi --run-time=$RUN_TIME --stop-time=$RUN_TIME vlc://quit
```